# How do I install unicodecsv 0.12.0 on a mac

Tags: python

The following commands are not working:

```
sudo pip install unicodecsv
```

I get

```
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.4.1
```

with

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

I get

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

I downloaded the package from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.12.0).  How do I install from the download?

Comment: when you say it's not working... what doesn't work about it?

Comment: sorry.  I added the errors I get.

Comment: Why is this tagged as iOS and then there is the `apt-get` command? Isn't it from Debian based linux distro's?

Comment: @ODiogoSilva I have no idea.  I'm just a noob trying to learn.

Comment: You seem to have pip installed, just not the right version for the module you're  trying to install. Do you have easy_install installed as well?

Comment: @ODiogoSilva how would I know?

Comment: @dwstein type in the terminal `easy_install --version`. It should return the version of setuptools if it is installed

Comment: it didn't recognize `--version` but it did allow me to call `--help`, so I guess it's in there.

Comment: Try to install the specific pip version using the command: `sudo easy_install pip==1.4.1` and then, if successful, run `sudo pip install unicodecsv` again.

Comment: great! I'll put it in the answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the specific pip version required for the package:

```
sudo easy_install pip==1.4.1
```

And then repeat the pip install command:

```
sudo pip install unicodecsv
```

Comment: easy-install should be easy_install